# Edge browser on raspberry pi?

Tags: raspberry-pi, microsoft-edge

Is it possible to get the Edge browser running on the raspberry pi 2?

I've seen that in some areas the edge browser greatly outperforms Chrome (dom manipulation/css transitions), and I am creating a public display "art project".

Comment: It seems unlikely at this point as the current plans for windows10 on the raspberry pi 2 are running windows 10 IoT core rather than their traditional desktop.

Comment: @sam I dont need the entire browser, just a webview.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Microsoft Edge browser app is not included on Windows 10 IoT core that runs on the Raspberry Pi 2. However the same web platform behind MS Edge is available on the RP 2 in UWP apps. If you have a website you can take advantage of it through a Hosted Web App or the WebView control.

The steps to deploy an app are listed [here](http://ms-iot.github.io/content/en-US/win10/SetupRPI.htm). Check out this [blog](http://blog.getsetbro.com/webapp-on-raspberry-pi-via-windows-uwp.html) that covers the entire process of deploying on the Pi 2 through VS 2015. You are able to do this through the free [community version](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/visual-studio-community-vs.aspx).

This [video](https://channel9.msdn.com/Blogs/One-Dev-Minute/Creating-Hosted-Web-Apps-with-Project-Westminster) covers how to make a Hosted Web App. A fun project and demo app to deploy is here: https://github.com/MicrosoftEdge/JSBrowser. It's a tutorial JavaScript app browser built using the WebView control that is able to run on the Pi 2.

Comment: FYI: I did this project in about one hour (plus download times); excellent tutorials you've found there. I was expecting to use 5-10 hours of tweaking with Linux (in which I'm experienced) to get a nice boot sequence and start a browser in kiosk mode.

Comment: Awesome that's good to hear. You can set the JSBrowser to be the startup app pretty easily following these instructions: http://ms-iot.github.io/content/en-US/win10/tools/CommandLineUtils.htm